# Laravel / Envoyer production error - Class view does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, envoyer.io

I recently created a new production deployment for a new Laravel-based system. Initially, I had a few permissions issues with the storage folder that I resolved pretty easily. Once I resolved those, I had the app running correctly, but upon my next deployment (with Envoyer), I ran into a different issue that I haven't been able to pin down.

I'm now getting a fatal PHP error that I wasn't getting before:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not
>   exist in
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:719\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(719):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('view')\n#1
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(598):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')\n#2
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(567):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view')\n#3
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view')\n#4
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1139):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('view')\n#5
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framewo in
>   /var/www/Core/releases/20170804125010/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 719

I've played around with various permissions, tried manually running composer `install/update, npm install/etc`. with no resolution.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clear the cache and check the error log to get the exact error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a bit of experimentation with no luck, I think I resolved it. The Ubuntu user that was set up for deployment with Envoyer was, by default, deploying everything with the 'envoyer' group permissions. This created a permissions conflict with the actual app permissions on Ubuntu.  I updated the default group for the deploying user to 'www-data' and it seems that everything is cleared up now.

Comment: How do you do that?